# Removing fields from BibDesk

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibdesk

Apologies if this question has been posted somewhere else, but I have not managed to find an answer that works for me.

I am trying to create a bibliography using Harvard style, using BibDesk to create the .bib file, and Biber and BibLatex.

However, the bibliography contains the DOI, the URL, the ISSN, a further e-print URL - all things I do not want.

My question is: is there a way to delete these fields in BibDesk, so that they are absent in the .bib file?

Comment: Why not just disable printing of these items using `biblatex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to remove these fields from the `bibtex` files. All you have to do is to use the `isbn`, `dii` and `url` option of biblatex and set them to false, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[doi=false, issn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
```

Alternatively you can use

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{<field>}}
```

to remove other unwanted fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry that seemed pretty obvious, but (as you can probably tell) I am fairly new to Latex.

Answer (score 0):

Put this before the bibliography:

```
\def\url#1{}
```

I got this from http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2006-May/022510.html

It works on my laptop.